# How to cast a string to a WebControl.Button

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have over 100 asp.net buttons that I need to set the BackColor and Text directly from a database, if I can figure this out I can replace a 400+ line Select statement with about 10 lines of code.  Neither of the below conversion methods work, if they did I could replace the `b.ID` with the var `c` in the If clause.

```
    Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim taR As New DsReadyTableAdapters.taReady
    Dim dtR As New DsReady.ReadyDataTable
    taR.Fill(dtR)
    Dim x As Integer = 1
    Dim ss As String
    Dim t As Type
    For Each b In form1.Controls
        t = b.GetType
        If t.Name = "Button" Then
            Dim c As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button = CType(b.ID, System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button) 'tried both, doesn't work
            Dim c As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button = DirectCast(b.ID, System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button) 'tried both, doesn't work
            ss = CStr(b.ID).Substring(6)
            If ss > 122 And ss < 126 Then
                b.ID.BackColor = Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(dtR(x).Color) 'b.ID is string so doesn't work
                b.ID.Text = dtR(x).Num
                x += 1
            End If
        End If
    Next b
End Sub
```

I have also tried using a `Controls.OfType` clause in the `For Each` statement to narrow the results to just the buttons, but to no avail.  I am willing to do this with jQuery also but have not found a straightforward method of pulling the data from the database that is as easy as what I am using.  Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found that jQuery offers a straightforward easy way to accomplish this, iterating through HTML elements, buttons in this case.  Add a class name to the buttons you're trying to find.  Thanks for your help.

```
function dealer() {  // for Deal
        var i = 0;
        $('.deal').each(function(){ //need class="deal"
            var chit = deal[i];
            if (chit.length == 2) {
                var v = chit.slice(0, 1);
                var c = chit.slice(1);
            } else { // 3
                var v = chit.slice(0, 2);
                var c = chit.slice(2);
            }
            (this.value) = v; // Number
            switch (c) {
                case "r":
                    (this.style.backgroundColor) = "red";  // Color
                    break;
                case "b":
                    (this.style.backgroundColor) = "lightblue";
                    break;
                case "g":
                    (this.style.backgroundColor) = "gray";
                    break;
                case "o":
                    (this.style.backgroundColor) = "orange";
                    break;
            } // switch
            i++;
            event.preventDefault();
        }); //deal
    }; // dealer
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Dim button As Button = CType(form1.Controls["your_button_name"], Button)
```

Comment: where exactly would you put that in the code, before the `For Each` statement?  I'm trying to iterate through all the buttons so I don't see how I can use `your_button_name`.  Thanks

Comment: "try" is not adequate description for an answer.  Code-only solutions are considered poor-quality content, and may cause your answer to be deleted.

Comment: put it in your loop, your_button_name = b.ID

Comment: thanks @Jack, I tried both Button and HtmlButton to no avail, bottom line I don't think a string can be converted to an element, so far I haven't been able to do this in VB or jQuery

Comment: `Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlButton'.`